# PhpStorm - double indentation for arrays

Tags: php, arrays, settings, phpstorm, indentation

I am one of many developers who prefer tab indentation over spaces, regardless what FIG recommends or sets as standard.

I have set up PhpStorm a few days ago and I'm evaluating it (I use PDT Eclipse).

I have one issue, which is extremely annoying in PHP Storm and I can't seem to find a setting or a solution to it:

I like to indent arrays with 2 tabs and also close the brackets with the same indentation as the keys of the array (see example below). Is there a way to have PhpStorm use this kind of indentation or at least to stop it from forcing its own indentation in arrays?

```
$arr = array(
        'key1' => 'value1',
        'arr1' => array(
                'key2' => 'value2',
                ),
        );
```

Comment: I had to choose between double indentation and the other cool features of PhpStorm, so I chose PhpStorm. I have settled with using just one tab for array indentation, even though all my code has all the arrays double indented - I am refactoring as I go. Not the coolest solution, but you can't have everything I guess :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to set up double indentation in code style. But that would make double indents everywhere. Even though I understand it does not answer your question I would suggest to **stick to sensible approach and use only one tab everywhere** (maybe setting 8 space wide tabs).